# Set Content size of scroll view dynamically does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

```
-ViewController
--View
---ScrollView
----View
-----TextView
-----Label
-----etc
```

I am trying to set **contentSize** of **UIScrollView** by following.

```
let lastView : UIView! = scrollView.subviews.last
let height = lastView.frame.size.height
let pos = lastView.frame.origin.y
let sizeOfContent = height + pos

scrollView.contentSize.height = sizeOfContent
```

But, it's not working. Any suggestions ?

Comment: make sure you get correct data for lastView. Debug it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you have to provide scrollview constraints like top to superview, leading to superview, bottom to superview, trailing to superview.

Then provide scrollview's subview known as view constraint like leading, trailing, bottom and top constraint to scrollview.

And then provide scrollview's subview known as view constraint like equal width and equal height to the main view.

And change the lastly provided constraint equal height priority to 251.

This should make scrollview dynamically change accroding to the content.

Try it!!!

Comment: OK, I tried it. It does not work. You're telling iOS that the scrolling content is the same height as the screen (or some other fixed area), which in many (or most) cases is wrong. If the actual contents you're trying to scroll are shorter than the screen, you end up with a bunch of empty space at the bottom. If the contents are taller than the screen, they get cut off. Is this not true?